# How to retrieve a youtube playlist id using Regex and JS

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

I'm trying to retrieve playlist ids from youtube links like:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv_X327YUdI&list=SPGznEl712WelO6ZhS8lc2ssweLuQaCKld
```

or

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=SPGznEl712WelO6ZhS8lc2ssweLuQaCKld
```

And to reject links not belonging to youtube.

So in this case the outcome would be:

```
SPGznEl712WelO6ZhS8lc2ssweLuQaCKld
```

Comment: I'm not sure how specific you want to be, but: http://jsfiddle.net/KByLm/2/

Comment: what if the link is like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=SPGznEl712WelO6ZhS8lc2ssweLuQaCKld&v=hv_X327YUdI     ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize what was different between the two links you provided. Here's something: http://jsfiddle.net/KByLm/4/ . It works, but it's probably far from perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it:

This function validates that the link is from youtube:

```
    function youtube_validate(url) {

        var regExp = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com(?:\S+)?$/;
        return url.match(regExp)&&url.match(regExp).length>0;

    }
```

This function retrieves the playlist id

```
  //get playlist id from url
    function youtube_playlist_parser(url){

        var reg = new RegExp("[&?]list=([a-z0-9_]+)","i");
        var match = reg.exec(url);

        if (match&&match[1].length>0&&youtube_validate(url)){
            return match[1];
        }else{
            return "nope";
        }

    }
```

Comment: I needed to add a `-` so... `[a-z0-9_-]`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i suppose you have already extracted the links:

```
var link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv_X327YUdI&list=SPGznEl712WelO6ZhS8lc2ssweLuQaCKld';

var reg = new RegExp("[&?]list=([a-z0-9_]+)","i");
var match = reg.exec(link);
alert(match[1]);
```

explanation

```
[&?]       one of these characters
list=
(          capture group 1
 [A-Za-z0-9_]+  all characters that are in [A-Za-z0-9_], one or more times
)          close capture group 1
```

Answer (score 2):

get playlist id from url

```
function playlist_id(url) {
    var VID_REGEX = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/
    var regPlaylist = /[?&]list=([^#\&\?]+)/;
    var match = url.match(regPlaylist);
    return match[1];
}
```

get video id from playlist url

```
function video_id_from_playlist(url) {
    var VID_REGEX = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/
    var video_id = url.match(VID_REGEX)[2];
    return video_id ;
}
```

or video id from url

```
function get_video_id(url) {
    url = url.split(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/);
    return (url[2] !== undefined) ? url[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_\-]/i)[0] : url[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(?:youtube.com.*(?:\?|&)(?:list)=)((?!videoseries)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)

(group #1)

Some playlist id's have "-" https://regexr.com/3h5gs
np:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldY6WNjEmGY&list=RDw9pC-51IQ60&index=6

Sorry for German techno :> first what i found