# Getting Youtube video IDs on the page and setting to playlist param

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I have a function that I'm using in order to add parameters to any youtube videos showing on a page and it currently works

```
 <p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Vdwef9DF?start=1" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"  allow="autoplay"></iframe></p>

 const youtubeUrlPattern = /^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$/;

  [...document.querySelectorAll('iframe')].filter((iframeEl) => {
    // Filter to iframes loading YouTube URLs only.
    return iframeEl.src.match(youtubeUrlPattern);
  }).forEach((iframeEl) => {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = iframeEl.src;
    a.search = a.search || '?';
    a.search += '&autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1&rel=0';
    iframeEl.src = a.href;
  });
```

However, I also want to add the playlist parameter like `&playlist={videoID}`

How can I get the id from any youtube url in this case and create a variable to properly set this playlist attribute?

Comment: Check this out: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868181/how-to-retrieve-a-youtube-playlist-id-using-regex-and-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve a youtube playlist id using Regex and JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868181/how-to-retrieve-a-youtube-playlist-id-using-regex-and-js)

Comment: Do you think this can help you? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/wj97b6rx/)